# Excel: how to link cell from one sheet to another

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

could you please, help me?
i would like to find out how to do this:
i have a sheet 1: with columns: number, name, color. 
i would like on sheet 2 to have 3 cells, where after entering the number, two other cells will give me appropriate name and color.
Sheet 1 is my catalog, and the sheet 2 i need only from printing each items certificate.
thank you,
Elena

Answer (score 1):

In sheet 1, you have number, name and color in columns A, B and C. I suppose number is unique. Then, in sheet 2, you want to enter a number (say in cell A1) and in cell B1 you need the matching name and in C1 you need the matching color.

This can be done by putting the following formula's in sheet 2:

- In B1: `=VLOOKUP(A1; Sheet1!$A:$C; 2; FALSE)`
- In C1: `=VLOOKUP(A1; Sheet1!$A:$C; 3; FALSE)`

Note that I assume those sheets are in the same file. If they are not, instead of using `Sheet1` in the formula, use `[Filename]Sheet1`.

Comment: thank you, but something is not working here, i am getting " the formula contains an error' ?

Comment: it works good, but it's not working for the cell with a date in it!?thank you so much in advance!

Comment: @Elena: Please consider marking the answer as accepted.